# calculation of month as per Julian Calendar

Tags: c++, arrays, switch-statement, qt4, qt-creator

I'm a beginner in QT C++, and I'm trying to print Julian day on a `label_j` with respect the value mentioned in array list. I'm unable to do that. Please could you see and correct it. Thanks a lot in advance.

Current month is been fetch from the UTC,
  if month equal jan then print 0,
  month equal then print 31,
  month equal  March then print 59 and so on until it reach December.

```
void MainWindow::getJulianDay()
```

{

```
  int month_arr[]={0,31,59,90,120,151,181,212,243,273,304,334};
  QString January, February, March, April, May, June, July, August, September, October, November, December;

  QDateTime local(QDateTime::currentDateTimeUtc());
QDateTime UTC(local.toUTC());
QString month=UTC.toString("MMMM");



switch (month)
{

    case January:
        month=month_arr[0];
        break;
    case February:
         month=month_arr[1];
        break;
    case March:
        month=month_arr[2];
        break;
    case April:
        month=month_arr[3];
        break;
    case May:
        month=month_arr[4];
        break;
    case June:
        month=month_arr[5];
        break;
    case July:
        month=month_arr[6];
        break;
    case August:
        month=month_arr[7];
        break;
    case September:
        month=month_arr[8];
        break;
    case October:
        month=month_arr[9];
        break;
    case November:
        month=month_arr[10];
        break;
    case December:
        month=month_arr[11];
        break;
    default: month=invalid;
    break;

    ui->label_j->setText(month);


}
```

Comment: Does your code compile? Your `switch` syntax seems wrong, i.e. you never specify the case value: `case 1: ...`. You assign a string to an int, i.e. `month="January";`. You assign an int to a QString, i.e. `answer=month_arr[0];`.

Comment: @m7913d ...thanks for you concerned, So, what will be the exact code for the same, please will you show me here. thank a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two main mistakes :

First of all, your `case` statement conditions are empty. You should do :

```
switch(variable) {
    case condition1:
        ...
        break;
    case condition2:
        ...
        break;

    ...

    default:
        ...
        break;
}
```

So, your code becomes :

```
switch (month);
{
    case 1: 
        month="January";
        answer=month_arr[0];
        break;
    case 2: 
        month="February";
        answer=month_arr[1];
        break;

    ...

    default: 
        month="invalid";
        break;
}
```

The second main problem is that `ui->label_j->setText(answer);` should be out of the `switch` loop. As it is currently, this statement will never be executed.

Edit : As noticed by m7913d, you have a lot of type errors. Review the type of your variables !

Comment: thanks for you concerned, So, what will be the exact code for the same, please will you show me here. thank a lot